# Limited matplotlib functionality with gtkcairo backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk

I'm working on an application which embeds matplotlib into a python and gtk2 program and uses the gtkcairo backend for matplotlib. I'm successfully using axes.plot but if I try to use something like scatter() to make a colormap, or use an interactive tool like lasso, I get an error. This is reported in the problem details when the error occurs:

```
Most Recent Project: C:\Users\Documents\p\p.aprojx 
Platform: AMD64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Work\components\win64\lib\python2.7\matplotlib\backends\backend_gtk.py", line 435, in expose_event
    self._render_figure(self._pixmap, w, h)
  File "C:\Users\Work\components\win64\lib\python2.7\matplotlib\backends\backend_gtk.py", line 423, in _render_figure
    self.figure.draw (self._renderer)
  File "C:\Users\Work\components\win64\lib\python2.7\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Work\components\win64\lib\python2.7\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Work\components\win64\lib\python2.7\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Work\components\win64\lib\python2.7\matplotlib\axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\Work\components\win64\lib\python2.7\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Work\components\win64\lib\python2.7\matplotlib\collections.py", line 717, in draw
    for x in self._sizes]
TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

I'd like to know what the problem is and if there's anything I can do about it. At the moment I'm thinking that gtkcairo is the problem, or using gtk2 instead of 3, but I'm not sure if changing either of those things is feasible at the moment.

Here is the code which is working fine, however if I change plot() to scatter() or anything else I hit an error.

```
def plot(self, x, y, xlabel, ylabel, semilogX = False, semilogY = False, plot_circles = False):
    self._figure.clear()
    axes = matplotlib.axes.Subplot(self._figure, 111)
    self._figure.add_axes(axes)

    if semilogX:
        axes.set_xscale('log')
    if semilogY:
        axes.set_yscale('log')
    if plot_circles:
        self.pts = axes.plot(x, y, 'o', c='blue', alpha=0.4)
    else:
        self.pts = axes.plot(x, y, ',', c='blue')
    axes.set_xlabel(xlabel)

    # the extra space is a hack for what appears to be a bug in the GTK backend where it draws
    # the y label horizontally, then rotates it to be vertical, but it does not figure out the
    # extent of the text correctly so leaves the trailing edge of a character (e.g. the leg of
    # an 'h' behind) - the ' ' means the left behind object is not very visible...sigh
    axes.set_ylabel(ylabel + ' ')
    configure_axes(axes, True)
    self.canvas.show()
```

Comment: Please post your code, without it we can't help.

Comment: What are the type of the x and y inputs?  Are they numpy arrays, or lists, or something else?  Also, what happens if you use `axes = self._figure.add_subplot(111)` instead of the manual construction?

Comment: Can you please post stand-alone code?  Try removing the alpha, I know PS does not support alpha blend and not sure about cairo.